# Is there a way of parsing information from smarty?

Tags: smarty, smarty-plugins

I have three files, a weather.php file which contacts an API and returns weather to my weather.tpl file. However I want to take the contents of the weather.tpl file (which only contains the api response) and post it to another page, any ideas about how I can go about doing this? I'm using smarty version 3.1.33.

Here are my files.

```html
// Weather.php

<?php

$ch = curl_init();
$location = 'MyLocation';
$apikey = 'MyApiKey';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='.$location.'&appid='.$apikey);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);//Free up system resource
$output = json_decode($output, true);
echo "The weather in ".$location." for MusicWorks Festival will be ".$output['main']['temp'];
?> 


//weather.tpl

{block name="weather"}

{/block}


//account.tpl (where I want the contents to end up)

<div>
  {block name="weather"}The weather: {/block}
</div>
```

I have used smarty like this to display both pages.

```html
{extends file="layouts/main.tpl"}

{block name="body"}
```

Comment: Which smarty version are you using?

Comment: @progman I'm using 3.1.33

Comment: Isn't it just a `{include 'weather.tpl'}` call?

Comment: @Progman no, is doesn't display anything, whereas if i go to the weather.tpl page it loads the weather, it just doesn't get carried across

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the source code how you use the smarty engine and how you display the templates (like `account.tpl` and `weather.tpl`).

Comment: There is still something missing. How do you get from "weather.php", which has no smarty code at all, to "weather.tpl"? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].